# Uncaught ReferenceError:foobar is not defined (anonymous function)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this js file serving from some domain say `foobar.com`

```
at http://foobar.com/static/js/main.js:

$(document).ready(function() {
        function foobar(bar){
            $.ajax({
                    url: "/site/foo/",
                data: {'foo':bar},
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    crossdomain: !0,
                    success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
                    },
                    error: function () {
                    }
                })
        }   
    });
```

On `barfoo.com` on some url, I have something like this:

```
<script src='http://foobar.com/static/js/main.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>foobar('123456')</script>
```

When I hit that url : it says

```
Uncaught ReferenceError:foobar is not defined (anonymous function)
```

How to access function from other domains?

Comment: Your `foobar` is not a global function, so you can't invoke it as one...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You've defined "foobar()" inside the "ready" handler. It's therefore a local variable in that function, and invisible outside it.

You could add this to the end of the "ready" handler:

```
  window['foobar'] = foobar;
```

and then it'd be visible globally.

By the way this is something that can bite at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) because it (by default) will wrap code in a "load" handler.  Thus, if you copy/paste from a JavaScript file included in the `<head>`, a function that would be global in that context ends up not global in the fiddle.

Comment: It is fine to declared it as globally? Any side effect?

Comment: Well @Tauquir there could be side effects if the name of the function collides with another `window` property.

Comment: you can declare the function outside $(document).ready(function() {

Answer (score 0):

Your function is not visible globally as pointed out by Pointy. But you are also loading a script and calling a function defined by the `ready()` function. I guess it's possible `ready()` may not have been called when your script calls `foobar()` which would generate the same error. I would recommend you set a global value in your script and then use that variable in the `ready()` function.

Set the value in the script:

```
<script src='http://foobar.com/static/js/main.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>var bar = '123456'</script>
```

Then you can use it in the `ready()` function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
                url: "/site/foo/",
                data: {'foo':bar},
                dataType: "jsonp",
                crossdomain: !0,
                success: function (data) {
                   alert(data);
                },
                error: function () {
                }
            });  
       });
```

If you want to define a function so you can use it again you can call it in `ready()` but make sure you set the global variable `bar` to what you want.

```
window.foobar = function() {
        $.ajax({
                url: "/site/foo/",
                data: {'foo':bar},
                dataType: "jsonp",
                crossdomain: !0,
                success: function (data) {
                   alert(data);
                },
                error: function () {
                }
            });
       }

$(document).ready(function() {
    foobar();
    // other stuff 
});
```